What is the translation of a jammer in French?
From wikipedia.org:

A jammer, also called a swim jammer, is a style of swimsuit worn by male swimmers, used mainly in competition to obtain speed advantages. They are generally made of nylon and lycra/spandex material, but may be made of polyester, and have a form fitting design to reduce water resistance. The materials usually dry fairly quickly. They provide moderate coverage from the mid-waist to the area above the knee, somewhat resembling cycling shorts or compression shorts worn by many athletes. They provide greater leg coverage than swim briefs and square leg suits, although they also have slightly more water resistance.

Example from swimoutlet.com:

What is the translation of jammers in French?
My findings:

Google Translate doesn't translate the term.

larousse.fr doesn't have the term.

Linguee doesn't suggest any interesting translations.

OQLF notes "L'emploi de l'emprunt jammer est déconseillé."



@FrançoisJurain https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26560111/cuissard-de-natation "L'emploi de l'emprunt jammer est déconseillé."

Jolly good! Now you know cuissard de natation and at least 2 viewers believe your post would gain by mentioning it. Just add a couple words about what makes it unsuitable in your case (ideally although not necessarily, a sentence that looks awkward featuring it) and I'll be delighted to upvote it.

@FrançoisJurain Knowing different options is part of learning a language.

Using comments to improve your question is part of getting upvotes. And enlightening options in answer. For cuissard de natation to come up in answers, the piece of data only you can provide is, it will not do to just borrow the English word.

@FrançoisJurain "cuissard de natation" came up in answers before I wrote that comment, so you're wrong.

I see. Then let me just say you'll get one less VTC and one more upvote by stating in so many words leaving "jammer" untranslated is not acceptable.

Cuissard de natation

Maillot de bain moulant, fabriqué en matériau extensible, qui couvre de la taille au bas de la cuisse.

(OQLF).
